# Cronjob isn't working properly

Tags: php, cron

I am using the below mentioned code to run cron job. I am running the cron job every minute. The cron file checks the whether there is a new data available for a particular user or not. If there is then just insert that into the database.

**Problem**
I have checked in the SSH using  **tail -n 10 /var/log/cron** command and it says that the cronjob ran a minute ago, which is great but it didn't entered the data in the database as there was a new data available. When I went directly on the URL it successfully added the data. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong, any guidance will be great.

**Cronjob Code**

```
*/1 * * * * wget http://www.disciplinexgames.com/runkeeper/index.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

**PHP Code**

```
$query = "Select * " .
         "from data_feeds " .
         "where username='mark@example.com' " .
           "and gadget_data_type='Weighin' " .
           "and gadget_data_type_id='3283123'";

$result = $dbCon->query($query);

//check if it is a new id..

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
    //Insert into database..
}
```

Comment: Do you have any pages included in php page ? That can cause issue if path is not absolute

Answer (score 0):

Few ideas:

1. Use `/usr/bin/wget` instead of `wget`
2. Put URL in quotation marks
3. Redirect result to file like `> ~/cron_debug.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar code `CRON-STUFF wget http://page.com/path/script.php --delete-after >/dev/null 2>/dev/null` to trigger cron PHP scripts so i think there isnt the problem.

Some ideas.

- Did you put in the MySQL connection stuff in the stand alone script (one think i mostly forget)
- Did you executed the command without cron and does it do the job? If yes are there some permission (file / user) problems with the script?

Comment: yes MySQL connection is there and if I execute the URL **http://www.disciplinexgames.com/runkeeper/index.php** it works properly then. The file and user permission is 0644/10002 505

Comment: You executed the URL part inside the browser or the complete wget part via ssh? I mean the latter. And 644 sounds good i think.

Comment: I executed the URL part inside the browser not the complete wget part via ssh

Comment: Then please try that also. Then you also get a direct response from the console and the debugging should be easier. If the user who executed the cron is another one then you are currently via ssh, its a good idea to switch to the web user to get correct debugging results.

Comment: I mean to switch to the User Who executes the cron.

Comment: @borhrsi thanks for your time I checked properly and the result was the root directory's usage was 100% because cron was sending output in there. I have deleted the unnecessary files and it is working now!!